# VBA Copy Paste values not properly

Tags: excel, vba

How can I copy-paste **the values** between workbooks, because is not doing properly on all the cells...what I'm doing wrong?... any advice would be very helpfull, thank you!

```
  Sub CopyPaste()

 Workbooks("LastData").Worksheets("East").Range("A3:BT3").Copy 
 Destination:=Workbooks("DATA.xlsm").Worksheets("AP").Range("A" & 
 Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
 Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:15:00"), "CopyPaste"

 End Sub
```

Comment: What you mean not doing properly?

Comment: @0m3r for example its swaping the values of 2 cells or in another cell where I have the time function its not copying it ( it copies only #### ), thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range1.copy range2` copies formulas and formats. If you want to copy *values only*, either use `PasteSpecial` or directly assign values (preference for the latter).

1-PasteSpecial

```
Workbooks("LastData").Worksheets("East").Range("A3:BT3").Copy
Workbooks("DATA.xlsm").Worksheets("AP").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp) _
   .Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

2 - Assigning values

```
Workbooks("DATA.xlsm").Worksheets("AP").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Range("A2:BT2") _ 
  .Value = Workbooks("LastData").Worksheets("East").Range("A3:BT3").Value2
```

The second method requires sizing properly the destination range, but it is preferred for being proper, fast and avoids the use of `copy/paste` stuff.